# Повторное использование объектов

Tags: android, java, шаблоны-проектирования

Добрый день. В моем проекте есть несколько классов, которые расширяют Fragment - это экраны. Для подключения экрана используется следующий код:

```
public void showScreen(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_screen_fragment, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

R.id.main_screen_frament - это контейнер, который используется для отображения экрана. Для того что бы показать экран я использую следующий код:

```
public class ShowMainScreen implements Command {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        ScreenManager.getScreenManager().showScreen(new MainScreen());
    }
}
```

Как видно при каждом новом вызове ShowMainScreen, будет создаваться новый экземпляр класса MainScreen. Это не верно потому что экран созданный один раз, можно без труда использовать снова.

Как можно хранить уже созданные экраны, для повторного использования?

Comment: самостоятельно кешировать ui в андоиде как то не принятно - чревато утечками памяти и непонятными глюками.

Comment: Тогда единственный правильный путь здесь - создавать при каждом показе новые экраны и работать уже с ними?

Comment: @KoVadim ну можно же использовать слабые ссылки

Comment: А смысл? андроид и сам все хорошо умеет кешировать.

В примере выше - здесь разве будет миллион экранов? да максимум десять. Не вижу смысла здесь кешировать их. Есть смысл кешировать данные.

Comment: сам андроид похоже кеширует layout'ы, так что ничего там не будет пересоздаваться.


Не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией.

Comment: при таком то создании фрагмента new MainScreen() что-то закешируется и не пересоздастся?

Comment: лучше пересоздавать, гугл сам продвигает фрагменты как легковесные объекты и советует их создавать каждый раз...

Comment: смотря, что там внутри конструктора:)

Comment: @KoVadim, интересно, давай варианты тогда, в каком конструкторе? напомню, что значения мы передаем через setArguments(..)..

Comment: а если вызывать replace c тегом, а при создании искать через findfragmentbytag. ну и поставить setRetainInstance?

Comment: @Gorets setRetainInstance можно поставить только если фрагмент располагается непосредственно в активити, если он находится в другом фрагменте, то такого сделать нельзя.   

Что касается слабых ссылок, например многим известная библиотека HoloEverywhere в своей реализации NavigationDrawer использует слабые ссылки, тем самым фрагменты не пересоздаются каждый раз, что приятно в пользовании с точни зрения пользователя.

Comment: Если не рэплейсить фрагменты, а добавлять их в backstack, то ни каких проблем не будет. Backstack используется не только для goBack, но и как просто хранилище из которого можно достать ранее загруженный фрагмент.

Если не подходит, то как вариант - можешь хранить тупо в памяти, но тогда будут проблемы как с утечками так и с самой памятью.

Comment: Я рад, что заданный мной вопрос вызвал у вас интерес. В конце, концов я поступил следующим образом - использовал создаваемые fragment только для отображения информации, как и надо было сделать с самого начала. За обработку команд к отображению информации на экране, если это необходимо отвечает специальный класс Manager+ИмяЭкрана. Внутри этого класса есть статическое поле которое содержит экран. При создании экземпляра Manager поле проверяется на null и если нужно экран создается. Это очень удобно поскольку позволяет оставить в классе, который описывает экран минимум кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания единственного экземпляра класса необходимо использовать шаблон проектирования Singleton. Вот примерная реализация:

```
public class SingletonMainScreen extends MainScreen {
    static private SingletonMainScreen instance;  
    // закрываем конструктор
    private SingletonMainScreen () {
        super();
    }

    public static SingletonMainScreen getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) 
            instance = new SingletonMainScreen();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Если нет желания городить класс наследник, то можно сделать фабрику или фабричный метод, которые также будут контролировать количество создаваемых экземпляров класса.

Comment: Комментарий перенесен из ответа: "Ответ Константина Смирнова не правильный, так как при смене ориентации экрана и при восстановлении `Activity` система будет вызывать дефолтный конструктор `Fragment()`, а не `getInstance()`. Кроме того, поскольку дефолтный конструктор `private`, будет сгенерировано исключение `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`"